# How to compare strings and make changes?

Tags: python

I have the below code which takes the user input (myWordsCopy) converts any characters entered in place of letters IE: @ = a, then converts any "badWords" to '*'.

The issue is that now the entire string is a new one with 'converted' words.

For example:

(for this example; badword == a bad word)

input - "I have an email address; @xyz but it includes a b@dWord"

currently prints - "i have an email address; axyz but it includes a ******"

what i want to print ;

"i have an email address; @xyz but it includes a ******"

I ideally would like to avoid adding every variation of "badWord" to my dictionary and rather compare any charters that are commonly used in place ie; @ = a , $ = s etc that is why I have taken the approach to convert the entire string.

I tried to compare a copy of the original string with the new string and replace every instance of **** in the new back to the original ,I tried with a nested for Loop but these were not 'synced' so it didn't work without changing the entire string again.

```
myWords = input("Enter words")
myWordsCopy = myWords.lower()
badWords = {"badword"}
wordDiction = { "@" : "a" , "$" : "s" }

for char in myWordsCopy:

    if wordDiction.get(char):

        myWordsCopy = myWordsCopy.replace(char, wordDiction.get(char))
      
for words in myWordsCopy.split(" "):

    if words in badWords:

        myWordsCopy = myWordsCopy.replace(words, '*'*len(words))
            
print(myWordsCopy)
```

Comment: We need a _complete_ code sample that we can actually run.  The code in this question has lots of undefined variables.  What is `myWordsCopy`?  What is `wordDiction`?  What is `badWords`?

Comment: This might be very difficult and actually encourage users to try to find a way around the problem.

Comment: @JohnGordon updated with those definitions

Comment: @Mous , it's not really the point....

Comment: In this specific case, `myWordsCopy` is all lowercase, but `badWord` contains a capital letter, so `if words in badWords` will never be true.

Comment: @JohnGordon Typo i have since fixed.

Comment: "which takes the user input (myWordsCopy) converts any characters entered in place of letters IE: @ = a, then converts any "badWords" to '*'." Okay, so then the issue is that this *isn't actually what you want it to do*. Instead, you want it to find ` badWords` but *treating* `@` as if it were `a`. My advice is to try to use functions to represent smaller parts of the problem. For example, can you write a function that takes a word and tells you whether it is bad or not?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel its a good point i could try that thanks .(I'm still learning python , trying to remember to compartmentalise some code)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

Pass each word in the string to a function, function converts the word if contains character , then checks if the word is in badWords, returns true or false.

then if return true , replace word with '*' * len(words)

```
myWords = input("Enter words\n")
myWordsCopy = myWords.lower()
badWords = {"badword"}
wordDiction = { "@" : "a" , "$" : "s" }


def wordCheck(badWording):
    
    for char in badWording:
        if wordDiction.get(char):
            badWording = badWording.replace(char, wordDiction.get(char))

    if badWording in badWords:
        return True
    else: 
        return False


for words in myWordsCopy.split(" "):

   if wordCheck(words) is True:
       myWordsCopy = myWordsCopy.replace(words, '*'*len(words))
    

print(myWordsCopy)
```